What is causing this code to output "Unreachable" and "continue and break not in the loop"?
The console is saying that "continue" and "break" are not in the loop.
print(f"Prime Number Checker")

while True:
    # Inputs
    integer = input("\nEnter an integer to test: ")
    # Processes
    number = int(integer)
    is_prime = True
    i = 0

    for i in range(2, number-1):
        if number % i == 0:
            is_prime = False
            break
    if is_prime:
        print(f"{number} is a prime number")
    else:
        print(f"{number} is a composite number because it is divisible to {i}")
        break
else:
    print(f"Invalid integer value! Try again")
    continue
option = input(f"Do you want to test another integer (y/n): ")
if option == "n":
    break
# Outputs
print(f"Bye!")

I tried to executed but nothing works.
The console should state this:
Enter an integer to test: 25
25 is a composite number because it is divisible by 5
Do you want to test another integer (y/n): y


The continue on the sixth-to-last line, and the break on the third-to-last line, are indeed not inside any loop.

Also using break or continue has its uses, but generally this wouldn't be such a case.
I would advise you to use a variable here instead of the while True, where you can set where you use break and continue whether the loop should end or not.

What are you hoping this code should do? When should the else: after the while: loop be entered?

You're right, they weren't in the loop. Still having an issue with link the "Invalid integer" statement with the if_prime. I need it to state that the integer is invalid if something other than a number is not entered.

Hi Camilla! Has this been solved? Do you still need help?

1. The keywords continue and break are only valid inside loops. Hence they cannot be used outside loops.
These lines are the culprits:
else:
    print(f"Invalid integer value! Try again")
    continue # <—— continue used outside loop.
if option == "n":
    break # <—— break used outside loop.
2. Having an else statement without a preceding if statement in Python will raise a SyntaxError exception because it is an invalid syntax.
else: # <—— This is an invalid syntax.
    print(f"Invalid integer value! Try again")
    continue

The error output "Unreachable" is probably because of one or more of the issues I just pointed out. I could be wrong but I couldn’t find the culprit for that.

Thank you. I'm stumped at this point. How do I revise this code so that if someone enters something other than an integer it will print out the "Invalid integer" statement. This is the main cause of the code not working properly.

I’m sorry you feel that way. I will not edit my answer because that is not what the question asked however I have cleaned up your code and tested it to the best of my abilities.

You can Try it online here and pick it up. You have the license to use it freely.
